# gnu parallel bash command with simple quote

Tags: bash, postgresql, gnu, psql, gnu-parallel

I would like to use Gnu parallel to parallelized a psql command like :

```
SELECT func('param', 10);
```

But as gnu parallel uses the simple quote to delimit the bash command, like :

```
seq 0 9 | parallel -jobs 10 'psql -c "SELECT func('param', 10);"' \> {}.log
```

this is not working.

I tried different ways, without success. 
So I really appreciate some help.

Comment: For GNU Parallel you would typically make a function and call that. This way you avoid all the \-circus and it will often make your code more readable. https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Calling-Bash-functions